# Loading and playing a movie as a texture in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, textures, movie

I have a strange situation where the following script will successfully load and play a movie texture in unity:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Tester : MonoBehaviour {

    MovieTexture _tex;
    Renderer _rend;
    bool _initTex = false;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        _rend = GetComponent(typeof(Renderer)) as Renderer;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        if (!_initTex) {
            initTex();
        } else {
            if (!_tex.isReadyToPlay) {
                Debug.Log("Waiting for _tex");
            } else if (!_tex.isPlaying) {
                _rend.material.mainTexture = _tex;
                _tex.Play();
            }
        }
    }

    void initTex() {
        WWW req = new WWW("http://www.unity3d.com/webplayers/Movie/sample.ogg");
        if (req.error != null) {
            Debug.Log("Error: " + req.error);
        } else {
            Debug.Log("Got movie = " + (req.movie != null).ToString());
            _tex = req.movie;
            _initTex = true;
        }
    }
}
```

However if I [download sample.ogg](http://www.unity3d.com/webplayers/Movie/sample.ogg) and put it in my assets folder and change the line:

```
WWW req = new WWW("http://www.unity3d.com/webplayers/Movie/sample.ogg");
```

to:

```
string path = Application.dataPath + "/Videos/sample.ogg";
WWW req = new WWW(path);
```

I get and endless `Waiting for _tex` message (see above). The `MovieTexture` is being successfully loaded but `_tex.isReadyToPlay` is never true.

What is going on here?

Also when the movie file does play there is often a long delay between loading and playing. Is there a more efficient way of loading and preparing a movie into a `MovieTexture`?

Answer (score 0):

The movie file needs to be placed into a folder (anywhere in Assets) called StreamingAssets.  Instead of using Application.dataPath, use Application.streamingAssetsPath.

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/StreamingAssets.html

This will ensure that no matter your target platform, the path is correct to find the movie.